# How google ads are shown on Android?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I did some testing with ads on my device and then pushed app to the play with with production unit ID. After a while when the version was available on play I deleted the debug build from my device and installed from [playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.osfg.tictactoe) .

The code is same as what [developer site](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/interstitial) suggests

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(callerActivity);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(callerActivity.getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
    Log.i(TAG," Interstitial Add :Loaded");
    mInterstitialAd.show();
}
else {
    Log.i(TAG,"Could not load Interstitial Add");
}
```

But surprisingly I see following in logs

> 2:38.743  16617-16617/com.osfg.tictactoe I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
>   06-17 18:22:38.743  16617-16617/com.osfg.tictactoe I/Ads﹕ Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("235F7FAA8F49FF2CAA1DD2FAFE6B9E8A") to get test ads on this device.
>   06-17 18:22:40.529  16617-16617/com.osfg.tictactoe I/GamePlayOnClickListener﹕ Game Over. Some player won
>   06-17 18:22:43.551  16617-16617/com.osfg.tictactoe I/GamePlayOnClickListener﹕ Could not load Interstitial Add
>   06-17 18:22:43.551  16617-16617/com.osfg.tictactoe I/GamePlayOnClickListener﹕ Resetting game

It is still using my device as test device? Not sure what is happening here. Anyone has any prior experience on this? I know it calculates the hash but does it store it on admob server but again this is client call. How would it know? I am confused. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most likely you're encountering this issue because `mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);` is calling a background thread to load a new ad, but you're checking to see if the ad has been loaded immediately. You don't give that background thread a chance to connect to the server, get the ad, etc.

To fix this, you need to place your code for when the ad has been loaded inside an `AdListener`, like so:

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        Log.i(TAG," Interstitial Add :Loaded");
    }
    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int error) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Could not load Interstitial Add");
    }
}
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

The if statement `if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())` is for checking at a later time if the ad has been loaded, such as after the user does some action. Not when an activity begins or anything similar.

Comment: Joseph you are 100% correct about why he is getting an error when calling `interstitial.show()` immediately after calling `loadAd()`. But telling people to call `interstitial.show()` from `onAdLoaded()` will get their account banned as Admob has said **many** times.

Comment: @Joseph and @Willam thanks for the info. But my question is around why does it say `addTestDevice` in the logs for app downloaded from play store with production add unit id.

Comment: @AniketThakur I might be mistaken, but it may just say that on any device. If you're going to test your app, you have to use test ads and you can get your Admob account banned if you don't. That's why you're seeing that message, because Admob needs to provide you will the ability to request test ads on any device. So I believe no matter what device you run on, yours or someone else's, real or emulator, you will see that message in the logs because any device may be used for testing. Does that make sense?

Comment: No I am using production add unit it and as admob says this unit id is for production and using it for testing may led to blocking your account. Considering that I downloaded the app from play store and opened it and I see above in logs. What I expect is that the adds should be without test device (considering it is downloaded from play store).

Comment: @AniketThakur There's only one kind of admob ad unit id that you can create for yourself. You can use any ad unit id for getting test ads, by including the line `AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("DEVICE ID HERE")`. So long as you're seeing actual ads in your app, you've done everything correctly. No matter what you do, you're always going to see that message in your logs.

Comment: That's what... my code is `new AdRequest.Builder().build()` meaning it does not have `addTestDevice()` in it. If the adds I see are infact test adds please suggest a way for me too see actual adds and not just test adds. Though I highly doubt those are test adds but I don't understand why does it print testdevice in logs.

Comment: @AniketThakur [This](https://developers.google.com/admob/images/ios-quickstart-15.png) is a banner test ad and [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/images/ios-interstitial-00.png) is an interstitial test ad. If your ads don't look like these, they're real. And that is printed in the logs for the reason I said before, you can use **any** device to get test ads but you have to include the `addTestDevice()` call with the **exact** code you see printed. If you haven't included that line, you're getting real ads, but the line will will **always** be in the logs, in case you ever need it.